# First Derivative filter Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have recently been tasked with using a first derivative filter on an image of myself. The instructor said that I should first fix the value of y and preform f(x+1) - f(x) on the rows and then fix the new "X" values and preform f(y+1)-f(y) on the columns.

Note: I have been asked to do this task manually, not using filter2() or any other programmed function, so please do not suggest that I use filter2() or similar. Thanks!

I tried calling up all the pixels and subtracting each successive one by doing

```
fid = fopen('image.raw')
myimage = fread(fid,[512 683], '*int8')
fclose(fid)

imsz = size(myimage)

x = imsz(1)

for I = 1:512
for J = 1:683

X(I) - X(I-1) = XX
```

But it doesnt seem to work, and I dont quite understand why. If you could help me, or point me in the right direction, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: I have no Matlba at hand and to be honestI will not write your code! So just a few suggestions: You have to write the variable you want assign an operation to on the left and not on the right. You must write X[i, :] to index one row or X[:, j] to index one column.

Comment: In addtion to what has been said in the comments/answer, I would advise against hard-wired upper bounds for loops. Instead assign the value to a variable or call `size` on the vector/matrix you wish to loop over. That avoids errors once you have to deal with arrays of different size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your code is syntatically incorrect:

1. There is no [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) statement to any of your loops, and besides, you don't even need loops here.
2. You seem to read your image into the variable `myimage`, but you're using an undefined variable `X` when attempting to calculate the derivative.
3. The order of your assignment statements is reversed. The variable you wish to assign to should be written in the left hand part of the assignement.

I strongly suggest that you read online tutorials and get yourself familiar with MATLAB basics before taking on more complicated tasks.

As to your specific problem:

MATLAB encourages vectorized operations, *i.e* operations on entire arrays (vectors or matrices) at once. To subtract adjacent values in an array, what you're basically doing is subtracting two arrays, shifted by one element with respect to each other. For one dimensional arrays, that would translate in MATLAB to:

```
a(2:end) - a(1:end-1)
```

where `a` is your array. The `end` keyword specifies the last index in the array.

To compute the derivative of an image (a 2-D matrix), you need to decide along which axis you want to perform that operation. To approximate the derivate along the y-axis, do this:

```
X(2:end, :) - X(1:end-1, :)
```

You can verify that this gives you the same result as `diff(X, 1)` (or simply `diff(X)`). To compute the approximate derivative along the x-axis, which is equivalent to `diff(X, 2)`, do this:

```
X(:, 2:end) - X(:, 1:end-1)
```

The colon (`:`) is the same as writing `1:end` as the array subscript for the corresponding dimension.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax issues, hastily typed in my code, and forgot a few lines that described X. Thanks for the help, very helpful

Comment: @user2475404 _"Haste is the devil..._"

Comment: @user2475404 : Please be courteous next time, and review your question carefully. You might not always be as lucky as today. You might also find [this website](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your filtered image is `div` then

```
for Y = 1:682
    for X = 1:511
        div(X, Y) = myimage(X + 1, Y + 1) - myimage(X,Y);
    end
end
```

Remember the last row and the last column are not filtered!